# Find the vertices of a square inscribed in a given triangle (figure) by vector methods

Tags: geometry, vectors, contest-math, triangles

> Given: a triangle ABC, with A=(1,1), B=(3,6), C=(6,2). Points M, N, are respectively on the sides AB and BC.
>
> Find: Coordinates of points P and Q on AC, such that MNPQ is a square (figure below) using vector methods.

[image]

Asked in a math contest. Hints and full solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the quickest way, but its uses general methods that could be used elsewhere.

Note that if you know $P$, $M$, $N$ or $Q$, you automatically knows the three other vertices by going along orthogonal or parallel lines to the triangle edges.  Orthogonal lines are rather easy to find in $\mathbb R^2$ : the orthogonal vector of $(a,b)$ is $(-b,a)$ (or $(b,-a)$).  For instance by interesecting the line orthogonal to $[AC]$ starting at $P$ with line segment $[AB]$, you can find $M$.  Likewise you can find $N$ by intersection $[BC]$ with the line from $M$ going in the same direction than $[AC]$.  And yet with the same trick, you can find $Q$.

By using a *test function*, you can evaluate whether $P$, $M$, $N$ and $Q$ are the vertices of a square.  Squares have orthogonal diagonal of same length that cuts in their middle.  So you must check that (where $||.||_2^2$ is the squared euclidean norm and $\langle.|.\rangle$ the scalar product) :

\begin{align}
\frac{M+Q}2 &= \frac{N+P}2\\
||Q-M||_2^2 &= ||P - N||_2^2\\
\langle Q-M | P -N \rangle &= 0
\end{align}
I.e. you must find a root to
$$
f : \left(\mathbb R^2\right)^4 \to \mathbb R : x \mapsto \begin{cases}
\frac{M+Q}2 - \frac{N+P}2\\
||Q-M||_2^2 - ||P - N||_2^2\\
\langle Q-M | P -N \rangle
\end{cases}
$$

Now let $P$ travel between $A$ and $C$, that is $P = t \cdot A + (1-t) \cdot C$.  Now you have constructed linearly $P$, $M$, $N$ and $Q$ depending on $t \in [0,1]$.  Hence by replacing $P$, $M$, $N$ and $Q$ by their expression in $t$ in the system above, you now have a giant second-degree equation system.  Solve it to find $t$ hence $P$ and $Q$.

**Note**: You are already guaranteed to have a rectangle thanks to the method of construction of $P$, $M$, $N$ and $Q$.  Therefore you only need to check the diagonals are orthogonal and solve $\langle Q-M | P -N \rangle = 0$.

**Note2**: Since $P$, $M$, $N$ and $Q$ is a rectangle, instead of checking whether the diangonals are orthogonal, you could simply check whether two adjacent sides have same length.  That it, you could solve  $||Q - P||_2^2 = ||M - P||_2^2$ to find $t$.

Comment: Great tutorial! Very helpful indeed.